# Consolidating & adding synonyms for cron, crontab & cronjob tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are  145 questions tagged with [cron](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cron), 61 with [crontab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crontab) & 17 with [cronjob](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cronjob).

Should these be consolidated into a single tag with appropriate synonyms? If so, would:

- [cron](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cron) ← [crontab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crontab)
- [cron](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cron) ← [cronjob](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cronjob)

be correct?

Comment: Hm, I'm not too sure. Issues related to editing a `crontab` are probably different from general questions about `cron`. It depends on how often these tags are used together anyway though.

Comment: `tag:cron` could also mean the particular implementation, as opposed to e.g. anacron. Some users might not have used `tag:cron` for that reason.